# Generating PDF documents from LISP

Tags: pdf, lisp, pdf-generation, document, rtf

I want to generate a technical report from lisp (AllegroCL in my case) and I studied various packages/project to help me do this.

### Requirements:

- Need to generate a PDF
- May create an intermediate format like RTF, Restructured TEXT, HTML, Word DOC or Latex
- Need to be flexible to be able to add content throughout my application
- Need to handle Multi-Page, Headers, Footers, Tables, inclusion of Images.

### Possibilities:

- **cl-pdf and cl-typesetting**: I checked this one out and it works for now, but is there a better alternative?
- Some **Latex generator**, but ???

### Question:

Do you know alternatives to easily generate (PDF) reports from lisp. What is the best workflow to go for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

we are using **cl-pdf and cl-typesetting** for the last 3 years and it has numerous issues... (like its confusion around encodings, or silently not rendering things that don't fit, or...) so, **i don't recommend** new development based on them.

currently we are in the process of **moving all our export mechanisms to [open document format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenDocument)**. openoffice is all happy with it, and there's a [plugin for ms office](http://www.sun.com/software/star/odf_plugin/), too.

there's .fodt, the so called flat open document text format, which is a mere xml file describing a document. generating it is as easy as generating xml files.

you can also [make parts of your document read-only](http://plan-b-for-openoffice.org/ooo-help/r2.1/en-US/WIN/shared/guide/protection) with a password (insert a section and mark it read-only and protected by a password. when generating the xml, you can generate random hashes as password...).